# Dlink DIR-300 pair as wireless bridge

Tags: dd-wrt, wireless-bridge, dir-300

Basic background:  I have/had enough experience to flash and do all that is necessary to install rd-wrt and setup etc.

I setup a wireless bridge a few years ago , 500 meters across the fields, from house to my workshop. So long ago I have little recollection of how or why I used the settings I did.  Been running fine for 3 or 4 years not even a re boot,  apart from power failures
So long in fact, I can't remember the setup routine

Setup consists of 4 'routers'

**1.** The broadband fibre internet connection, this acts as the only DHCP
    server. Vigor 2800G

**2.** House Attic; Belkin F5D8631-4  not wrt compatible, hardwired to the
    Vigor2800G. This is the Tx end AP for the wireless bridge.

**3.** Workshop Attic Other at other end of the bridge.  Linksys wrt54g with rd-wrt

**4.** Belkin F5D7230-4 hard wired to Linksys, solely as a wireless AP, in the workshop.

Trouble is my bridge pair have suffered the ravages of damp,  being in the attic.
Also the tree line is getting thicker, so going to need some directional antennas to 'help' the signal.  I have built some 20 element yogi antennas and tested them out with radio test kit borrowed from local amateur radio friend.  I get a good db gain using these antennas, and they are plumbed to fit the DIR-300 antenna sockets

So the issue is this, I need to replace routers 2 & 3, re rig the wireless bridge with the DIR300's

I have 3 x DIR-300's , two model A1's and a model B1.

I have seen the B1's can only use Repeater mode, but what about the A1's?
What is best Client or Repeater? mode or what is the difference ? will it make any difference to me?.
Only ever 2 or 3 users at the workshop AP end, and that is very low use access, occasional copy of files form home server and internet access for e-mails etc

Thanks for any help you can give